# Parse list of tuples

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse, parsing

I want to pass a list/sequence of "tuples" to a macro, like this:

```latex
\foo {
    (value11 value12 value13)
    (value21 value22 value23)
    (value31 value32 value33)
    (value41 value42 value43)
    (value51 value52 value53)
}
```

How do I define `\foo` so that it can process each tuple `(valuex1 valuex2 valuex3)` in the list one-by-one? It would also be good to know how to handle the situation where the "tuples" have variable length, though that's a side point, and I'll gladly accept an answer without that.

I imagine an xparse and/or expl3 answer will be what I'm looking for here, but I'm afraid xparse is just black magic to me, essentially.

Comment: What do you mean by “to process each tuple”? You're leaving out too many details that are instead needed in order to help. What's the reason for using `(...)` instead of `{...}` (which would make things much simpler)?

Comment: @egreg "Process each tuple" is extraneous to the question. I'm trying to create a minimal example and simplify the scenario. Just assume some arbitrary processing. But your second question is fair: `{ ... }` would be fully acceptable too.

Answer (score 4):

With `listofitems`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\ignoreemptyitems
\setsepchar{(||)}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \readlist*\z{#1}%
  \foreachitem\zz\in\z[]{%
    Processing tuple: \zz\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\foo {
    (value11 value12 value13)
    (value21 value22 value23)
    (value31 value32 value33 value34 value35)
    (value41 value42 value43)
    (value51 value52 value53)
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one needed a secondary loop to process the items in the (quin)tuple, then this would do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\ignoreemptyitems
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \setsepchar{(||)}
  \readlist*\z{#1}%
  \foreachitem\zz\in\z[]{%
    Processing tuple:
    \setsepchar{ }
    \readlist\zzz{\zz}
    \foreachitem\zzzz\in\zzz[]{%
      subitem: \zzzz\quad
    }%
    \par\medskip
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\foo {
    (value11 value12 value13)
    (value21 value22 value23)
    (value31 value32 value33 value34 value35)
    (value41 value42 value43)
    (value51 value52 value53)
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. That looks like a nice simple, readable solution. (I would be curious about an xparse solution too, but I suspect it wouldn't be so readable as this.)

Answer (score 1):

It's “more LaTeX” if the items are braced rather than in parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% no black magic, really

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {% #1 is a list of items in braces
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \noldorin_foo_process:n
 }

% now an example of \noldorin_foo_process:n

\seq_new:N \l__noldorin_foo_process_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \noldorin_foo_process:n
 {
  % split the argument at spaces
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__noldorin_foo_process_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  % print each item surrounded by angle brackets and follow each by \par
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__noldorin_foo_process_seq { $\langle$##1$\rangle$ \par }
  % then vertical space between each tuple
  \bigskip
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo {
    {value11 value12 value13}
    {value21 value22 value23}
    {value31 value32 value33}
    {value41 value42 value43}
    {value51 value52 value53}
}

\end{document}
```

Why `\tl_map_function:nN`? Because this will split the token list given as argument into “items”, that is, single tokens or braced groups. and apply the specified function to each of them in turn.

You now have to decide what actually `\noldorin_foo_process:n` should do.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes, that's surprisingly simple for xparse. All the xparse code I've seen up to now has been very confusing. Maybe I just need to read a good tutorial about it...